# JQGrid not populating data from url

Tags: json, jqgrid

Hello I am new to JQGrid and java too. I am trying to populate data to my JQGrid. If I add data locally it works fine. But if I try to access the json data saved to a file it does not work. I tried all other questions asked here but no help.

```
var mydata = [
          {"Path":"\\template\\604.rtf","SNo":"1","TemplateName":"604.rtf"},
         {"Path":"\\template\\Template_1.rtf","SNo":"2","TemplateName":"Template_1.rtf"},
       {"Path":"\\template\\Template_2.rtf","SNo":"3","TemplateName":"Template_2.rtf"}
          ];

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            $("#templatesGrid").jqGrid({            
                url:'gsonfile.json',                    
               datatype: 'json',
                type: 'GET', 
                height: 250,
                colNames:['SNo','Template Name','Path'],
                colModel:[
                    {name:'SNo',index:'SNo', width:50,sortable:false},
                    {name:'TemplateName',index:'TemplateName', width:350,sortable:false},
                    {name:'Path',index:'Path', width:550,sortable:false}
                ],
                multiselect: false,
                paging: true,
                pager : '#pager',
                rowNum:10,
                rowList:[10,20,30],
                pager: $("#page"),
                loadonce:true,
                caption: "Templates"
            }).navGrid('#page',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
        });
```

Below is my json file data

```
[{"Path":"\\\\template\\604.rtf","SNo":"1","TemplateName":"604.rtf"},
 {"Path":"\\\\template\\SampleTemplate_1.rtf","SNo":"2","TemplateName":"Template_1.rtf"},
 {"Path":"\\\\template\\SampleTemplate_2.rtf","SNo":"3","TemplateName":"Template_2.rtf"}]
```

Am I missing something?